# Loaded model with applied texture material is just black, don't know how to debug

Tags: three.js

I'm having an issue that three.js is not rendering my model. I load the model with `JSONLoader`, the texture with `ImageUtils.loadTexture` and create a `MeshPhongMaterial`. My question is about how to debug the issue, since the basic code works. That is, the exact same code works with a different model, and if don't use a texture I do get a plain coloured version of my desired model. There's something wrong with the combination of model/texture which I don't understand and I have no idea how I can debug it.

How do I figure out why it doesn't render?

---

I've tried exporting the new file cube from blender and it has the same problem. So the source model is not likely the problem, though the export could be.

Comment: check the network tab in the webkit inspector to make sure all images are loading?

Answer (score 1):

My models didn't have UV coordinates, so even though I had exported UV the list was empty. This of course means that the texture cannot be applied. Logically there is no way to "compute" the UV coordinates in three.js. I added the UV data in blender, exported again, and it works.